# Installing lxml in Windows - unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm currently running Python 3.5.1 on Windows 10 and I'm having trouble installing the lxml module as I get the error message `unable to find vcvarsall.bat`, when using `pip install lxml` and `easy_install lxml`.

After browsing this forum I've seen that I need a visual studio compiler so I've downloaded both 2008 and 2015 and found that the 'vcvarsall.bat' file is in the following location: `....AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0`, how can i now point python to this location? Or am I missing something really fundamental here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: I did read through that @DavidZemens , however I couldn't see any relevant support for Python 3.5.1. Have you seen something I missed?

Comment: I probably have not, but I have only suggested this as *possible* duplicate. the vcvarsall.bat problem happens in different modules and different version of python.  On that same thread, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18045219/1467082) answer mentions some quirks with python 3.x though and specifically that you probably can't use Visual Studio 2008.